# Any way to see SignalR InvokeAsync return on postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman, blazor, signalr

Is there any way to recieve the return value from InvokeAsync in postman?
I have a SignalR server, with this method:

```
    public async Task<string> StringTest()
    {
        return "This was returned!";
    }
```

It works when called form a SignalR client (Blazor).

When called in postman it wont't show any message.
The steps I follow are:

1. url: **wss://localhost:44379/testhub**
2. Send handshake request
   `{ "protocol": "json", "version": 1 }`
   The response sohuld be empty if succesful, and now you will start recieving KeepAlive pings (type 6). [MessageType enum docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/messagetype?view=signalr-js-latest)

- Note that there is a special characer at the end that sends the message, but it seems that it can't be displayed as text, if you copy the code it is actually there, in postman there should appear as a square at the end (**All SignalR requests from postman need this character**).
  [image]

3. Send the request with:

```
{
    "type": 1,
    "target": "StringTest",
    "arguments": []
}
```

4. There is no response.

As a test, I tried:

```
    public async Task<string> StringTest()
    {
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Postman", "This was sent!");
        return "This was returned!";
    }
```

And the the response was:

`{"type":1,"target":"Postman","arguments":["This was sent!"]}`
Of course this is not the "returned" but rather "sent" by the server and is not treated as a return in an actual client like a Blazor application.

Is there any way to see the returned value?